# Strongly retained array empty

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an NSArray that I fill with SKTexture to animate an animal leaping:

```
    @interface PSFrogNode ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *leapFrames;

@end

@implementation PSFrogNode {

}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        SKTextureAtlas *frogLeapAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:kFrogLeapAtlas];

        int numImages = frogLeapAtlas.textureNames.count;
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numImages];
        for (int i=1; i <= numImages/2; i++) {
            NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"frogLeap%d", i];
            SKTexture *temp = [frogLeapAtlas textureNamed:textureName];
            [tempArray addObject:temp];
        }
        self.leapFrames = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
        self = [PSFrogNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[self.leapFrames objectAtIndex:0]];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)animateFrogLeap
{
    [self runAction:[SKAction animateWithTextures:self.leapFrames timePerFrame:0.09 resize:NO restore:YES]];
}
```

The array self.leapFrames is allocated in the init method but when the scene calls the animateFrogLeap method it's empty (meaning nil).
 Why is that?

Comment: Empty and `nil` are two completely different things. Which one is it really?

Comment: Could it be because the `init` method never runs?

Comment: Could it be that other code (not shown) has come along and changed `self.leapFrames`?

Comment: `self = [PSFrogNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[self.leapFrames objectAtIndex:0]];` - Why are you doing that, assigning back to self? That will mean you've lost your reference to `self.leapFrames`?

Comment: Could you please add some NSLog statements in the init method to log if objects are being added and also another NSLog in the animateFrogLeap to see if init is being called before animateFrogLeap? if you'd do that and share with us would be helpful to try to find some more clues.

Comment: also, its OK to assign an NSMutableArray to an NSArray pointer. So you can write self.leapFrames = tempArray;

Comment: The init method runs. in it the array is fine (has 12 objects in it). The assigning back to self Rich asks about is from a ray wenderlich tutorial about spritekit.

Comment: The array is nil in the animateLeapFrog method not empty

Comment: @user1028028, try assigning a leapFrames after assigning to self. Also, it's better not to use properties in the `init` method. Use an instance variable instead (`_leapFrames = ...;`). But I don't remember, why :)

Comment: I see the problem, yes after the self - [psforg node... the array becomes nil

Comment: How can I set the picture that the node should have when it's not animated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create the array outside of the `init` method and then pass it in:

**When creating the view**

```
SKTextureAtlas *frogLeapAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:kFrogLeapAtlas];

int numImages = frogLeapAtlas.textureNames.count;
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numImages];
for (int i=1; i <= numImages/2; i++) {
    NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"frogLeap%d", i];
    SKTexture *temp = [frogLeapAtlas textureNamed:textureName];
    [images addObject:temp];
}

PSFrogNode *node = [[PSFrogNode alloc] initWithImages:images];
// Now use the node
```

**PSFrogNode.h**

```
-(instancetype)initWithImages:(NSArray *)images;
```

**PSFrogNode.m**

```
@interface PSFrogNode ()

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *leapFrames;

@end

@implementation PSFrogNode 

-(instancetype)initWithImages:(NSArray *)images
{
    self = [self initWithTexture:[images firstObject]];
    if (self) {
        _leapFrames = [images copy];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
    return self;
}
```

As mentioned in my comment, the below line in your original implementation would mean that `self` would be reassigned, so the line before it (assigning the array to the property) would then be meaning less.

```
self = [PSFrogNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[self.leapFrames objectAtIndex:0]];
```